# IOS 12.4 Device Support files for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Does anybody have the iOS 12.4 device support files for older Xcodes?

I need it for Xcode 10.1.

Thank you

Comment: I too need them. did you get the files?

Comment: @FirozAhmed https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases The Answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases), you can get the 12.4 Support file from this link and add in the DeviceSupport folder.

Comment: This worked for me. We can probably keep renaming that folder until iOS 13 drops

Comment: What should exactly be done with this files inside the .dmg image?

Comment: @Isaac Earlier the support files for 12.4 was not available, so just replacing the content in 12.3 to a new folder 12.4 would resolve the issue. Now the latest files are available in that link you can use those files.